# What is this command doing? sed

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sed

I was given a general set of commands used as an example for something I will have to perform:

```
1 cat /etc/dsh/machines.list | sed -e "s|\(.*\)|sshfs \1:/opt/dextor/cloud \1|"
2 cat /etc/dsh/machines.list | sed -e "s|\(.*\)|sshfs \1:/opt/dextor/cloud \1|" | sh
3 cat /etc/dsh/machines.list | sed -e "s|\(.*\)|cp run.sh \1/|" 
4 cat /etc/dsh/machines.list | sed -e "s|\(.*\)|cp run.sh \1/|" | sh
```

What exactly is this doing?

I understand that the contents of machines.list are being passed to sed but what is the sed command doing?

Thank you!

Comment: Just wrapping each line of `/etc/dsh/machines.list` into those commands, with `\1` replaced by each line's content. I have to say this is a very strange way of doing things.

Comment: better way of sed commands would be sed "s|^.*$|sshfs &:/opt/dextor/cloud &|"

Comment: @josifoski Better not use sed at all.

Comment: This is an unnecessary use of the back reference notation (`\n` where n is a single digit) when in this instance the whole of the pattern in the lefthand side of the substitution command is used in the righthand side. The `&` is the correct metacharacter to use in this case.

Comment: @josifoski  `s|.*|sshfs &:/opt/dextor/cloud &|`, no need of `^` and `$` if you take `.*`

Comment: cat is not needed, sed can directly take the file as argument avoiding a thread and sub shell due tot shell pipe also because sed only transform each line, not the file content in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain `cat /etc/dsh/machines.list | sed -e "s|\(.*\)|cp run.sh \1/|"` to you and rest all are same.

1) `cat` will read lines from `machines.list` and pass that to sed.

2) sed is doing basically a `match and replace` operation.

`|` is used as a separator, it could be any character, and it's usually `/`. It basically work like this `|match this|replace with this|`.

You are matching `\(.*\)` which basically is telling sed to match everything in line. 
`.` matches to every character and `*` means to match that character any number of times. 
Using `()` will save that match in `\1`.

And in replace section you are replacing that with the text `cp run.sh \1/` and `\1` will be contain whatever is matched.

Also i do think there is no need to use `cat` at all. Better use it this way `sed -e "s|\(.*\)|cp run.sh \1/|" /etc/dsh/machines.list`

Comment: And look that useless use of cat. Not to mention other weirdos.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation. Do you have any ideas why for example line 1 and 2 are basically identical except for the last pipe?
Also why is there an "s" before the |\(.*\)|?

Comment: @ProgrammedChem `line 1` will simply give output on screen while `line 2` will send that output to shell for execution as command.  Why both lines are present there, you should ask person who gave you these commands. In my thinking `line1` will tell you what is going to be executed and `line2` will execute that. It might be just to make things better. `s` before `|(.*)|` is short for `search and replace`.